# Difference between dexter/sinister and rectus/laevus?

Tags: etymology, meaning, differences

Is there a difference between the pair dexter/sinister (right/left) and rectus/laevus?

I was only aware of the pair dexter/sinister until recently, when I learned that chiral molecules in molecular biology are labeled "D" and "L" to signify right- and left-handed versions. These letters are apparently inspired by *dexter* and *laevus*, which is perhaps extra surprising since it seems like this combines one word each from two common pairings, rather than sticking to a single pairing (e.g., "D" and "S", or "R" and "L".)

Comment: There's yet a third word for left, scaevus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Dexter* and *rectus***

"Dexter" is the term for "right" as in one's right hand.  "Rectus" never means "right" in this sense; it means straight, upright, direct, or correct, but it doesn't mean right as the opposite of left.

***Sinister*, *laevus*, *scaevus***

"Sinister" has a much longer entry than the other two in the Oxford Latin Dictionary, and is described by Ernout & Meillet (*Dictionnaire étymologique de la langue latine*)  as "the usual term" for "left".

"Laevus" is regarded by Lewis & Short as "mostly poetic".

"Scaevus" is described by Ernout & Meillet as "used above all in augural language or in figurative senses".  E & M note that "the names for 'left' are various (by contrast with those for 'right')".